# How to upload multiple files using webclient UploadFile, UploadValues in C#?

Tags: c#, webclient

How to upload multiple files using webclient UploadFile, UploadValues in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This blog post](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/azamsharp/archive/2007/10/25/Upload-Multiple-Files-Using-WebClient.UploadFile-Method.aspx) details exactly how to upload multiple files using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

If you want to upload both form fields and a file in the same POST, you can't use WebClient as-is-- instead it will need to be extended. Here's an excerpt from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72232/Csharp-File-Upload-with-form-fields-cookies-and-he.aspx) explaining what is needed:

> the only option is to create a custom
> implementation that conforms to
> [rfc1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867), [rfc2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) and the [W3C
> multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) specification that
> will enable file upload with
> additional form fields and exposes
> control of cookies and headers.

Here are three implementations, using slightly different approaches, but all should work to enable multi-part form data:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72232/Csharp-File-Upload-with-form-fields-cookies-and-he.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx
- http://aspnetupload.com/Upload-File-POST-HttpWebRequest-WebClient-RFC-1867.aspx

[WebClient.UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues.aspx) is not designed to upload files-- instead it's used to send POST-ed form values to the server.  You want to use [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) to upload files, or one of the advanced samples above.

Comment: Oh no! Your link to blog, point to this post, instead of actual blog entry. Can you please fix it?

Comment: I think this solution is not good for me, because i send every file in separate POST and without UploadValues i can't send any more information. Can you help me send files in one POST and with additional data?

Comment: OK, now I understand what you're trying to do. I revised my answer, which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm sad i can't give you more reputation points. As soon i will finish choosing one of your links, i will mark this as an answer. Or i just mark it now. ;]

Comment: I used http://aspnetupload.com/Upload-File-POST-HttpWebRequest-WebClient-RFC-1867.aspx and it works just great, this makes it really easy, nu "advanced" usage there!

Comment: Link to blog post now broken.