# Upload and get Json response as a cURL call in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, curl, httprequest

I'm trying to upload a file to the hosting platform Lutim using C#. 
In their documentation (https://git.framasoft.org/luc/lutim/wikis/API) they are using a cURL call:

```
curl -F "format=json" -F "file=@/tmp/snap0001.jpg" https://lut.im
```

And get back the following response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": {
        "real_short": "abc",
        "short": "abc/def",
        "token": "ghijkl",
        "thumb": XXX,
        "filename": "myimage.png"
    }
}
```

When I'm using WebClient, HttpWebRequest or WebRequest, like in this sample:

```
using (WebClient uploader = new WebClient())
{
   var data = uploader.UploadFile(new Uri(url), fileName);
   var result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
}
```

I always get back the HTML content of the target page, and not a JSON response as with the cURL call.

How can I get the same behavior of the cURL call in C#?
(without having to call cURL from C#...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supplying both form-data parts. You're missing the "format=json" part.

Have a look at

- [UploadFile with POST values by WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048258/uploadfile-with-post-values-by-webclient)
- [How to upload file to server with HTTP POST multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data)

for ways to pass both values