# How can I specify form name in WebClient.UploadFile?

Tags: c#, .net, http-post, webclient

`WebClient` is a very decent layer of abstraction when compared to `HttpPostRequets`, in *most* situations.

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    return webClient.UploadFile(url, path);
}
```

However, the class doesn't seem to include an option for the **name** of the input field. Here, `"file"` must be the name of the input field.

**From Wireshark**

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"

Is there a way to specify the "name" field, without going back to HttpPostRequest?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `NameValueCollection`? Also, there is a [different question that might be of interest.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048258/uploadfile-with-post-values-by-webclient)

Comment: I've seen this question and also a code [project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8600/UploadFileEx-C-s-WebClient-UploadFile-with-more-fu), but I'm thinking there must be a way to change the name of the input field using a supported way of `WebClient`. Microsoft wouldn't just "assume" every file must be in a control called exactly **"file"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that this is hardcoded. [View source here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/35714320/) for WebClient, head to line 573.

Looks like you will have to implement that portion yourself if you would like to do that. I found blog post that looked promising (since it had the name customized). [You can find that here](https://dzimchuk.net/post/uploading-a-file-over-http-in-net).

Comment: So it looks like we really can't change the name here. Hopefully, Microsoft will make it available as a parameter some day...

Comment: Realized this when calling the webapi from the VS-MVC-angular based frontend is calling api via webclient.UploadFile - the API needs to have same name as file - if you are using (the recommended) - IFormFile file in .net core 2